# Limit Options in a Select Dropdown using CSS

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, display, dropdownbox

I am in need of limiting dropdown option items in a `<select>` element. I am working within a CMS system, so I can't alter the HTML and can only use CSS to achieve this.

I currently am using:

```
select option:not([value="1"]){display:none;}
```

This works for most cases, except Edge (the dropdown box is still the size of 10 options) and on Mobile (my phone is still displaying all 10 options). Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Which options you trying to hide ? is it based on how many there is or their attributes or What ?

Comment: It's a quantity dropdown. The default is 10 tickets, but I want to limit the user to only 2 tickets.

Comment: The first 2 tickets, last 2 tickets, some 2 tickets in the middle ?

Comment: The first 2 tickets. Basically, it asked the user: how many tickets do you want? and when they click on the select dropdown, I only want 1 and 2 to display instead of the default 1-10.

Comment: `:nth-child(n+3){display:none;}` should only leave the first 2 visible.